# pandas data aggregation based on column filters

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a data frame like this

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
A     A1    X     1      2
A     A2    Y     2      2
A     A3    Z     1      2
B     B1    X     2      2
B     B2    Y     2      2
B     B3    Z     1      2
```

And i have a mapping like this.

**mapping**

```
col1  col3
 A --> X
 A --> Y
(A,B) --> Z
(A,B) --> (Y,Z)
```

This mapping works like a filter option that we use in excel.
for eg: For **A-->X**, we'll filter A from col1 and filter X from col3, and get the sum from col4

for **(A,B)-->Z**, we'll filter both A & B from col1 and Z from col3, whatever sum we get from col4 should be stored.

I have tried groupby and pivot_table methods but couldn't be able to cover all the cases in mapping.

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index= [col1,col3], columns = col3, values = col4, aggfunc='sum')
```

My expected result is.

```
col1  X   Y   Z   YZ
A     1   2   2   6
B             2   6
```

Is there any way to get this using groupy or pivot_table, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
        "col2": ["A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "col3": ["X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z"],
        "col4": [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
        "col5": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index):

```py
# Get values
df = df.groupby(["col1", "col3"]).agg(list)["col4"].apply(lambda x: x[0])

print(df)
# Output

col1  col3
A     X       1
      Y       2
      Z       1
B     X       2
      Y       2
      Z       1
```

```py
# Assign values to new dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in ("X", "Y"):
    new_df.at["A", i] = df.loc[("A", i)]

for i in ("A", "B"):
    new_df.at[i, "Z"] = df.loc["A":"B", "Z", :].reset_index().sum()["col4"]
    new_df.at[i, "YZ"] = df.loc["A":"B", "Y":"Z", :].reset_index().sum()["col4"]
```

```py
# Cleanup
new_df = new_df.fillna(0).astype(int).replace(0, "")
new_df.columns.name = "col1"
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)

# Output
col1  X  Y  Z  YZ
A     1  2  2   6
B           2   6
```